# how to extract fields from pdf in python using pdfminer

Tags: python, django

I have a pdf form that I need to extract email id, name of the person and other information like skills, city, etc..how can I do that using pdfminer3.[image]
please find attached sample of  pdf

Answer (score 1):

First, use tika to to convert PDF to text.

```
import re
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install tika
from tika import parser
from io import StringIO
from itertools import islice 

file = 'filename with directory'
parsedPDF = parser.from_file(file) # Parse data from file
text = parsedPDF['content'] # Get files text content
```

Now extract desired fields using regex.
You can find extensive regex tutorials online. If you have any problem implementing the same, please ask here.

Comment: I am able to read the pdf as text format..now how can I recognized what is the name of the person..because in pdf there is no keyword as the name

Answer (score 0):

Try to use tika package:

```
from tika import parser

raw = parser.from_file('sample.pdf')
print(raw['content'])
```